# How to get the current filename without the extension with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.co
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[^.]+\.(domain\.co)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ /somefile.php [L]
```

The bit that says `somefile` needs to be the filename that the user is on without the extension. So if they are at `example.com/file`, then `file` should be retrieved.

I have tried using the code below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.co
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[^.]+\.(domain\.co)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ /$.php [L]
```

The bit that says `.php` in the rewrite rule should not be part of the filename retrieved and is manually added.

If there is no way to do this without getting the extension, how could this be done regardless of the extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this rule **above your existing rule** to add `.php` extension:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add .php extension if corresponding .php file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain\.co$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !/$ /somefile.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I think you misunderstood the question. The file that is retrieved should be the base filename itself. When I said `somefile`, that was just an example. This code leads to an Internal server error. Also, for the `RewriteCond` for domain.co, does the line you wrote have the same effect as the two lines I had before?

Comment: What URL you want to show in browser and how you want to rewrite it internally? Yes `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain\.co$ [NC]` is sufficient instead of 2 conditions you have.

Comment: So if the user visits `example.com/post`, the URL should remain the same in the browser but they should be pointed to `example.com/post.php` (if all the other conditions are true - the domain isn't `domain.co` and the file without the `.php` does not exist. This should be **universal** though, so it may not just be `example.com` for the domain, it could be anything such as `test.com`.

Comment: ok that's what my rules are already doing. First rule rewrites `example.com/file` to `example.com/file.php` if `/file.php` exists. If `/file.php` doesn't exist then 2nd rule is used. You should check Apache `error.log` for the reasons of 500 error.

Comment: Should I remove the `/somefile.php` part, since it's based on the filename the user visits? Should it be replaced with `$`?

Comment: You can test with just the first rule but do check Apache error.log for the reasons of 500 error

Comment: This is the error received: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167663/discussion-between-anubhava-and-osman).